# When Querying a .csv file with OleDB, only some dates are coming back as DBNull

Tags: sql, vb.net, csv, oledb

In my application, I have to pull data from some comma-delimited .csv log files and put that info into a DataTable. The problem is that some of the DateTime values in these files are being read as DBNull by the OleDbDataAdapter. Most values work as expected, but any timestamp between 12:00:00 PM and 12:59:59 PM is being read as DBNull instead of a valid DateTime.

When the line is written, it uses the default ToString value of Now in the following way: `logLine = Now & "," & Environment.UserName & "," & ...` Because other reporting processes rely on these log files, this date formatting can't be changed. The log files are written by the same instance of the same application running on the same machine, so there shouldn't be any time zone/locale issues at play.

Some examples of how these dates look in the log files:

```
Timestamp,User,FileName,ClientID,Sender,FileType,LogType,LogMessage,InEmail
7/3/2023 12:00:00 AM,testuser,123456_testuser_EmployeeImport.csv,123456,testuser,EmployeeImport,System,"this time reads as 12PM",False
7/3/2023 1:00:00 AM,testuser,123456_testuser_EmployeeImport.csv,123456,testuser,EmployeeImport,System,"this time works",False
7/3/2023 11:59:59 AM,testuser,123456_testuser_EmployeeImport.csv,123456,testuser,EmployeeImport,System,"this time works",False
7/3/2023 12:00:00 PM,testuser,123456_testuser_EmployeeImport.csv,123456,testuser,EmployeeImport,System,"this time is DBNull",False
7/3/2023 12:59:59 PM,testuser,123456_testuser_EmployeeImport.csv,123456,testuser,EmployeeImport,System,"this time is DBNull",False
7/3/2023 1:00:00 PM,testuser,123456_testuser_EmployeeImport.csv,123456,testuser,EmployeeImport,System,"this time works",False
7/3/2023 11:59:59 PM,testuser,123456_testuser_EmployeeImport.csv,123456,testuser,EmployeeImport,System,"this time works",False
```

And here is the function that I've been using to fill the DataTable:

```
Public Shared Function QueryLogs(sql As String) As DataTable

        Try
            Dim strConnString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & LogPath & ";Extended Properties='text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited;IMEX=1'"
            Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(strConnString)
            Try
                conn.Open()
                Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
                Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter()
                Dim dt As New DataTable()

                da.SelectCommand = cmd
                da.Fill(dt)
                da.Dispose()
                Return dt
            Catch ex As Exception
                Return Nothing
            Finally
                conn.Close()
            End Try
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return Nothing
        End Try

    End Function
```

And for completeness's sake, here's an example where I use that QueryLogs function

```
dt = QueryLogs("SELECT * FROM [" & dateInput.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & " Log.csv]")
```

I would understand if the date formatting in this file was inconsistent or just completely incompatible with OleDbDataAtapter, but this method works perfectly fine for all other values that I've tested. There's just something different about the hour of 12:00:00 PM to 12:59:59 PM that makes my OleDbDataAdapter fail to recognize those strings as a valid DateTime.

Is there a way to force OleDb into reading the column as a string? I tried adding IMEX=1 to the extended properties of the connection string, but that didn't help in this case.

Comment: Please provide some sample CSV data that we can copy and paste to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Suggestion: have you tried [CsvHelper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper)?

Comment: According to [Data Type Support for OLE DB Date and Time Improvements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/ole-db-date-time/data-type-support-for-ole-db-date-and-time-improvements?view=sql-server-ver16#data-formats-data-structures) the use of _AM_ and _PM_ isn't supported. Also see [Conversions (OLE DB)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/ole-db-date-time/conversions-ole-db?view=sql-server-ver16). If you change the times to 24-hour format and remove the AM/PM designator, then you can use _OleDb_. Otherwise, you'll have to find another means of parsing the file.